# Column Drill Down Chart - parsing rendring via XML datasource

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an XML tree that I am parsing and seting Column Drill down HighChart options. But the HTML renders a blank page:

ex.xml

```
<chart>
     <categories>
        <name>'MSIE'</name>
        <name>'Firefox'</name>
        <name>'Chrome'</name>
        <name>'Safari'</name>
        <name>'Opera'</name>
      </categories>
      <name>'Browser Brands'</name>
      <data>
             <series>
               <y>55.11</y>
               <drilldown>
                  <name>'MSIE versions'</name>
                  <categories>
                      <name>'MSIE 8.0'</name>
                      <name>'MSIE 6.0'</name>
                      <name>'MSIE 7.0'</name>
                      <name>'MSIE 9.0'</name>
                  </categories>
                 <data>
                     <series>
                       <y>33.06</y>
                       <drilldown>
                           <name>'drilldown next level'</name>
                            <categories>
                              <name>'a'</name>
                              <name>'b'</name>
                              <name>'c'</name>
                            </categories>
                            <data>
                              <point>23</point>
                              <point>54</point>
                              <point>47</point>
                             </data>
                       </drilldown>
                     </series>
                   <point>10.85</point>
                   <point>7.35</point>
                   <point>2.41</point>
                 </data>
               </drilldown>
             </series>
             <series>
               <y>21.63</y>
                <drilldown>
                <name>'Firefox versions'</name>
                <categories>
                    <name>'Firefox 3.6'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 4.0'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 3.5'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 3.0'</name>
                    <name>'Firefox 2.0'</name>
                </categories>
                 <data>
                    <point>13.52</point>
                    <point>5.43</point>
                    <point>1.58</point>
                    <point>0.83</point>
                    <point>0.20</point>
                 </data>
               </drilldown>
             </series>
             <series>
               <y>11.94</y>
               <drilldown>
                <name>'Chrome versions'</name>
                <categories>
                   <name>'Chrome 10.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 11.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 8.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 9.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 12.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 6.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 5.0'</name>
                   <name>'Chrome 7.0'</name>
                </categories>
                <data>
                   <point>9.91</point>
                   <point>0.50</point>
                   <point>0.36</point>
                   <point>0.32</point>
                   <point>0.22</point>
                   <point>0.19</point>
                   <point>0.12</point>
                   <point>0.12</point>
               </data>
               </drilldown>
               </series>
               <series>
               <y>7.15</y>
               <drilldown>
               <name>'Safari versions'</name>
               <categories>
                   <name>'Safari 5.0'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 4.0'</name>
                   <name>'Safari Win 5.0'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 4.1'</name>
                   <name>'Safari/Maxthon'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 3.1'</name>
                   <name>'Safari 41'</name>
               </categories>
               <data>
                   <point>4.55</point>
                   <point>1.42</point>
                   <point>0.23</point>
                   <point>0.21</point>
                   <point>0.20</point>
                   <point>0.19</point>
                   <point>0.14</point>
               </data>
            </drilldown>
           </series>
           <series>
              <y>2.14</y>
               <drilldown>
               <name>'Opera versions'</name>
               <categories>
                  <name>'Opera 11.x'</name>
                  <name>'Opera 10.x'</name>
                  <name>'Opera 9.x'</name>
               </categories>
                <data>
                   <point>1.65</point>
                   <point>0.37</point>
                   <point>0.12</point>
                 </data>
                </drilldown>
            </series>
        </data>
</chart>
```

Code:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <title>Highcharts Example</title>


                <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
   var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
   var color=0;
   var options = ({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
         text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
      },
      subtitle: {
         text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
      },
      xAxis: {
         categories: []
      },
      yAxis: {
         title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
         }
      },
      plotOptions: {
         column: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
               events: {
                  click: function() {

                     var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                     if (drilldown) { // drill down

                         this.series.chart.setTitle({
                             text: drilldown.name
                         });

                        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
                     } else { // restore
                        this.series.chart.setTitle({
                                text: chart.name
                         });
                        setChart(name, categories, data);
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            dataLabels: {
               enabled: true,
               color: colors[0],
               style: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
               },
               formatter: function() {
                  return this.y +'%';
               }
            }
         }
      },
      tooltip: {
         formatter: function() {
            var point = this.point,
               s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
            if (point.drilldown) {
               s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
            } else {
               s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
            }
            return s;
         }
      },
      series: [],
      exporting: {
         enabled: false
      }
   });


  $.get('ex.xml', function(xml) {
                var $xml = $(xml);
                $xml.find('chart categories name').each(function(i, category) {
                        options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
                });
                $xml.find("chart data series").each(function(i, series){
                                        var seriesDownSearch = function(){
                                                var series = $(this);
                                                var seriesOptions = {
                                                        name: 'Browser Brands',
                                                        y: parseInt(series.find('y').text()),
                                                        color: colors[color],
                                                        drilldown : []
                                                        };
                                                series.find("drilldown").each(function(i, drilldown){
                                                        var drilldown = {
                                                                name : $(drilldown).find('name').text(),
                                                                color: colors[color],
                                                                categories : [],
                                                                data : []
                                                        };
                                                        $(drilldown).find('categories name').each(function(i, name) {
                                                                drilldown.categories.push($(name).text());
                                                        });
                                                        $(drilldown).find("data").each(function(i, data) {
                                                                var data = {
                                                                point: []
                                                                };
                                                                $(data).find('data point').each(function(i, point) {
                                                                        data.push(parseInt($(point).text()));
                                                                        drilldown.data.push(data);
                                                                        seriesOptions.drilldown.push(drilldown);
                                                                        options.series.push(seriesOptions);
                                                                });
                                                                color = color + 1;
                                                                $(data).find("series").each(seriesDownSearch);
                                                        });
                                                })
                                        };
                        });
                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                        //chart.series.setTitle.push($xml.find('chart name').text());
        });

   function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
      chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
      chart.series[0].remove();
      chart.addSeries({
         name: name,
         data: data,
         color: color || 'white'
      });
   }
});
                </script>

        </head>
        <body>

                <!-- 3. Add the container -->
                <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


        </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure whats the issue is and why the chart is not being rendered?

==================================================================================

Modified / Updated code:

I did some modification in my code but still I am not able see the Column DrillDown graph in browser using the same XML tree structure mentioned above in the thread.
I get only the title 'Browse Market Share,April,2011' and everything else is blank. 
Note the code at line 127 and 128 - I was not able to find a method to set the chart initial series name and level method. Please help me out in completing my project? I am completely stuck with the issue:

```
     1  <html>
     2          <head>
     3                  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     4                  <title>Highcharts Example</title>


     5                  <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
     6                  <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script-->
     7                  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
     8                  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
     9                  <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>

    10  <script type="text/javascript">
    11  var chart;
    12  $(document).ready(function() {
    13     var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
    14     var index=0;
    15     var options = ({
    16        chart: {
    17           renderTo: 'container',
    18           type: 'column'
    19        },
    20        title: {
    21           text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    22        },
    23        subtitle: {
    24           text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
    25        },
    26        xAxis: {
    27           categories: []
    28        },
    29        yAxis: {
    30           title: {
    31              text: 'Total percent market share'
    32           }
    33        },
    34        plotOptions: {
    35           column: {
    36              cursor: 'pointer',
    37              point: {
    38                 events: {
    39                    click: function() {

    40                       var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    41                       if (drilldown) { // drill down
    42
    43                           this.series.chart.setTitle({
    44                               text: drilldown.name
    45                           });
    46
    47                          setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
    48                       } else { // restore
    49                          this.series.chart.setTitle({
    50                                  text: chart.name
    51                           });
    52                          setChart(name, categories, data);
    53                       }
    54                    }
    55                 }
    56              },
    57              dataLabels: {
    58                 enabled: true,
    59                 color: colors[0],
    60                 style: {
    61                    fontWeight: 'bold'
    62                 },
    63                 formatter: function() {
    64                    return this.y +'%';
    65                 }
    66              }
    67           }
    68        },
    69        tooltip: {
    70           formatter: function() {
    71              var point = this.point,
    72                 s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
    73              if (point.drilldown) {
    74                 s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
    75              } else {
    76                 s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
    77              }
    78              return s;
    79           }
    80        },
    81        series: [],
    82        exporting: {
    83           enabled: false
    84        }
    85     });
    86

    87  $.get('ex.xml', function(xml) {
    88                  var $xml = $(xml);
    89                  $('chart', $xml).children('categories').each(function() {
    90                          options.xAxis.categories.push($(this).find('name').text());
    91                  });
    92                                          var seriesDownSearch = function(){
    93                                                  var seriesOptions = {
    94                                                          y: parseFloat($(this).find('y').text()).toFixed(2),
    95                                                          color: colors[index],
    96                                                          level : index + 1,
    97                                                          drilldown : []
    98                                                          };
    99                                                          $(this).children('drilldown').each(function(){
   100                                                          var drilldown = {
   101                                                                  name : $(this).children('name').text(),
   102                                                                  level : index + 1,
   103                                                                  color: colors[index],
   104                                                                  categories : [],
   105                                                                  data : []
   106                                                          };
   107                                                          $(this).children('categories').each(function() {
   108                                                                  drilldown.categories.push($(this).find('name').text());
   109                                                          });
   110                                                          $(this).children('data').each(function() {
   111                                                                  $(this).children('series').each(seriesDownSearch);
   112                                                                  var data = {
   113                                                                  point: []
   114                                                                  };
   115                                                                  $(this).children('point').each(function() {
   116                                                                          data.point.push(parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2));
   117                                                                  });
   118                                                                  drilldown.data.push(data);
   119                                                                  seriesOptions.drilldown.push(drilldown);
   120                                                                  options.series.push(seriesOptions);
   121                                                                  });
   122                                                          });
   123                                                          index = index + 1;
   124                                                  };
   125                                                  $xml.find('chart > data').children('series').each(seriesDownSearch);
   126                  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
   127                  chart.series.name = $('chart', $xml).children('name').text();
   128                  chart.series.level = 0;
   129  });

   130     function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
   131        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
   132        chart.series[0].remove();
   133        chart.addSeries({
   134           name: name,
   135           data: data,
   136           color: color || 'white'
   137        });
   138     }
   139  });
   140                  </script>

   141          </head>
   142          <body>

   143                  <!-- 3. Add the container -->
   144                  <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


   145          </body>
   146  </html>
```

Finally how to set this chart options to the Chart?

The issue with setting the options to chart is that I cannot find a proper way to the set the chart options correctly. Since my function is recursive I am not sure how to create and properly set the chart options as processed from the XML tree?

Thanks in advance - please let me know how can I resolve the issue as I completely stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it does not contain JS errors?

```
$(data).find("series").each(seriesDownSearch);

according to me, it should be 

$(data).find('series').each(seriesDownSearch);
```

You can check this out for more info if you wish to:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/NULTY/15/

Comment: I have updated my question with my modified code. I am successfully able to parse the XML tree but not able to set it as chart options correctly.

Comment: @Prakash are you correctly getting the values? did u try an alert to see if you are getting the series, categories or whatsoever?

Comment: @Prakash http://jsfiddle.net/wcQBa/ just see this, the node value is not enclosed between single quotes

Comment: Ok thanks I would remove the single quotes from nodes value. alert shows me that values are correctly parsed  but issue is setting it as chart options. Somehow after reading the values setting it in an object and then as chart option is not happening properly

Comment: @Prakash check your function again

Comment: Yesh I have changed that also. Thanks for pointing but it did not resulted me in any error either